# SugarCRM: Direct Bean Property Access vs. getFieldValue

Tags: php, orm, javabeans, sugarcrm

In modern versions of SugarCRM, after you load data into a bean object

```
$account = BeanFactory::getBean('Accounts')
->retrieve_by_string_fields(array('name'=>'Q.R.&E. Corp'));
```

You can fetch data either by directly accessing the property

```
$account->name
```

or by using `getFieldValue`

```
$account->getFieldValue('industry')
```

Is there any historical reason that `getFieldValue` exists?  Is there a canonical way of deciding when to use `getFieldValue` vs the direct object property method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference I'm seeing is that it will not throw PHP errors if the field doesn't exist, and if it's a boolean value it will convert it to an integer. See the function definition...

```
function getFieldValue($name)
{
    if (!isset($this->$name)){
        return FALSE;
    }
    if($this->$name === TRUE){
        return 1;
    }
    if($this->$name === FALSE){
        return 0;
    }
    return $this->$name;
}
```

Comment: Ah, the all important "not throw PHP errors" — that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I want to clarify, PHP does not throw an error if the property does not exist. The only difference between accessing the property directly and using the getFieldValue method is that you will receive NULL with the property and FALSE with the getFieldValue method.

Take this example to prove PHP errors are not thrown, maybe a warning, but nothing fatal.

```
<?php

class TestClass {
    public $one = 1;
}

$testClassInstance = new TestClass();

var_dump($testClassInstance->one); // Result = int(1)
var_dump($testClassInstance->two); // Result = NULL
```

Just wanted to clarify because the original answer says "throw an error" and in the programming world "throw" would mean you could get an Exception which could be fatal to your application if not "caught".

Comment: Good clarification @tommymay -- although it's an unfortunately common parlance to use "throw an error" to mean "raise an error" or "an error happens".  It's also common (at least in PHP land) to treat warnings as errors to keep logs and dev mode clean, which means warnings/errors end up lumped in the same category.